# Report on Memorial gifts made in memory of a person

Tags: contributions, reports, honoree

I am new to CiviCRM.  How would I run a list of donors and their contact information who have made contributions in memory of someone?
Your help would be appreciated.
Thanks.
Felicia

Answer (score 2):

I've just released an extension that does this called [Soft Credit Custom Fields](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/com.megaphonetech.softcreditcustomfields).  It does more than the name suggests - it also allows searching by soft creditee from **Find Contributions** or **Advanced Search**.  See screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to generate this from the Soft Credit Report - **Reports menu >> Contribution Reports**, select **Soft Credit Report**.

Unfortunately, you're limited in the fields you can select there - notably, you can't add address fields, which I suspect you need.

There are two solutions I'm working on for a client who has your needs.  I expect to complete them in the next couple of weeks but they're sadly not ready yet:

- I'm rewriting the soft credit report to modernize it, including a bunch more potential columns (including the address fields).
- I'm adding an ability in Advanced Search to specify soft creditee.

If you reach out to me on https://chat.civicrm.org (my username is @junglebird) with your contact info, I can email you to get an advance copy of these new features.  Your feedback will help make them better suit your needs!